# Update parameter value when calling Task.Start()?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

How can I update the parameter `currentTime` being sent to `WriteToConsole` when `Task.Start()` is called?

In the example below, When I declare `task0`, the value of `currentTime` is set at *1/1/2000*. When `task0.Start();` is executed, the value of `currentTime` has changed to `DateTime.Now`. But `Console.WriteLine` displays '1/1/2000'.

What would I need to do to update the `currentTime` so that task0.Start() is called with the current value?

```
static void WriteToConsole(DateTime n)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n.ToString());
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    DateTime currentTime = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01);
    Task task0 = new Task(n => WriteToConsole((DateTime)n), currentTime);

    for (; ; )
    {
        currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        if (true)
        {
            task0.Start();
        }
        if (task0.Status.Equals(TaskStatus.Running))
        {
            // Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Need a little more context.  Are you wanting to create multiple instances of task0, each with its own currentTime?  In that case, you will want to create a new Task instance each time you are launching one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Task task0 = new Task(() => WriteToConsole(currentTime));
```

should work, since the variable is captured, not the value.

Comment: true that "the variable is captured, not the value", but DateTime is immutable and the captured variable will always point to the same immutable object. Calling `currentTime = [some new DateTime]` will not change the original immutable object, but merely reassign what `currentTime` points to (but the Task's captured variable will still point to the old immutable object).

Answer (score 0):

encapsulate the parameter in a wrapper class, like this:

```
private class DtWrapper
{ 
    public DateTime CurrentTime {get; set; }
}

DtWrapper currentTime = new DtWrapper { CurrentTime = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01) } ;
Task task0 = new Task(n => WriteToConsole(((DtWrapper)n).CurrentTime), currentTime);

for (; ; )
{
    currentTime.CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
    if (true)
    {
        task0.Start();
    }
    if (task0.Status.Equals(TaskStatus.Running))
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

if you have no specific reason for passing the current time as an argument (n => ...), then use ths's answer, it's much nicer factoring.